# Preventing a form from submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, html, submit

I'm trying to prevent a form from submitting if a certain textarea is not filled, using jQuery. However, the textarea doesn't need to be filled if the data is already in the database. I am using the following code, but the jquery does not seem to be correct.

HTML & PHP:

```
    <form id="form" action="page1.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="textarea" name="name1" placeholder="<?= empty($val1)? 'Enter your val here': $val1 ?>" /> 
    <p class="submit"> 
         <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> 
    </p>
    </form>
    <div id="log"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $("#form[input[placeholder='Enter your val here']]").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
       $('<div/>')
         .append('please enter the val first')
         .appendTo('#log');
     });   
    };
```

Comment: Do you want to elaborate on the *'doesn't need to be filled if the data is already in the database'*? Or is that just extra context info?

Comment: If we have the data already, when user submits the form, he can skip this textarea. hence the `placeholder="<?= empty($val1)? 'Enter your val here': $val1 ?>"` in the html, if the user however did not enter this data in the past, AND he is not entering it now, then I want to prevent the form from being submitted, otherwise - it is okay

Comment: What is that `textarea` syntax you are using? I learnt to declare it this way: `<textarea ...>this is the content</textarea>`, see also http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA

Comment: I tried changing it, but it has other consequences re the css, and this is working just fine up until now

Answer (score 1):

Your selector seems a bit off if you're trying to bind to the form's `onsubmit` event. The result of your selector now is probably nothing because it's an invalid selector. You were probably trying to do:

```
$("#form input[placeholder='Enter your val here']")...
```

But really, all you need is:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var name1 = $('input[name="name1"]', this);
    // if database empty and input is empty then prevent form submissions
    if (name1.attr('placeholder') == 'Enter your val here' && name1.val() == '') {
        $('<div/>')
            .append('please enter the val first')
            .appendTo('#log');
        return false;
    }
});
```

The logic above is such that the form will NOT submit if:

- The DB value was empty AND the user did not type anything in the box

In all other cases, the form will submit, because:

- Either the placeholder does not equal 'Enter your val here', or
- the user typed something in the textarea to save.

Comment: but textarea might be empty even if there is a respective value in the DB, it will only be in the placeholder.. and I want to make sure they can sum=bmit the form if we have this value whether from now or from the past

Comment: I just tried your selector, and it didn't work either :( the reason I wanted to use this method and not the secodn one you suggested is what I mentioned above, what happens if the data is in the db already? we don't mind if they don't enter it again? thanks!

Comment: @LucyWeatherford: Ahh, ok. I changed my example a bit.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to do this, how do I write the if's condition? if(input[placeholder]=='Enter your val here') - ? –

Comment: @LucyWeatherford: `placeholder` is an attribute. You have to find the input element with the selector `$('selector')` and use the `.attr()` method to find the attribute value. Hence the `$('input[name="name1"]').attr('placeholder')` in my example code.

Comment: Okay, I updated it and also tried your exact code, but it is still submitting :( Is it related to the face that the form is not submitted through jquery but through the html

Comment: Is this selector correct?: `$("#form input[name='name1'] attribute[placeholder='Enter your val here']")`

Comment: @LucyWeatherford: Not quite. If you're looking for the input element named "name1" within your form, whose placeholder attribute is equal to "Enter your val here", then the selector would be: `$("#form input[name='name1'][placeholder='Enter your val here']")`. This selector returns an `Array` of elements. More specifically, the result will be an array of one input element. It does not return the value of the element. I just noticed: `textarea` is not a valid input type. Text areas are created with the `<textarea></textarea>` HTML tag. Text boxes are `<input type="text" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Put a class on the textare so you'll know if it needs to be filled in or not:

```
<form id="form" action="page1.php" method="post"> 
<input type="textarea" name="name1" class="<?= empty($val1)? 'Required': 'Optional' ?>" placeholder="<?= empty($val1)? 'Enter your val here': $val1 ?>" /> 
<p class="submit"> 
     <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> 
</p>
</form>
<div id="log"></div>
```

And check if the field is empty and required:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    var $textarea = $('#form input');
    if ($textarea.val().trim().length == 0 && $textarea.hasClass('Required')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#log')
            .append('please enter the val first')
            .appendTo('#log')
            ;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

(Please excuse any syntax errors... This is just to provide the general gist of it.)

Additionally, consider disabling the submit button and showing the message all the time until the form is valid and ready for submission. That would be more user friendly in my opinion.

Comment: What's not working? Does the textarea get the correct class (Required/Optional)? Is the submit event handler getting called at all (check by adding an alert('on submit called') to its beginning)? Is the textarea "emptyness and hasClass"-test working? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Simply `return false;` whenever you don't want to submit

Comment: Ok I'm trying to do this, how do I write the if's condition? `if(input[placeholder]=='Enter your val here')` - ?